# Android's widget no working anymore with SDK 18

Tags: android, widget, android-4.3-jelly-bean

I updated my project's manifest and had set targetSdkVersion to 18. But now, my app's widgets are dead. I have a list in my widgets, and list's items have some various buttons but when I click on one of these buttons, all look like they're pressed and nothing happens... I don't understand what can do that, and I found nothing on the web.
To declare actions on press, I used setOnClickPendingIntent on each items. It was working perfectly on on 4.2 and before.

If you have an idea, you're welcome.
And if you need some details or some lines of my code, just ask! :)
Thanks!

Comment: I guess, that setting the targetSDK is the version you're building against, meaning also, that "this attribute informs the system that you have tested against the target version and the system should not enable any compatibility behaviors to maintain your app's forward-compatibility with the target version." My question - is your failed widget using some kind of compatibility package or does it run on compatibility mode?

Comment: Widgets were developed with Android.app, Android.widget and Android.content, no compatibility package were used.